Coravel has issue with cron values
I'm trying to implement the Coravel library in my project; however, I have difficulty getting it to work correctly with 'cron' values.
It works for every second cron expression (* * * * ) or ( * * * 4);
However, when I set it to run 2 minutes from the current time with the cron expression 30 14 * * *, the method does not execute (it is currently 2:28 PM).
Project: .NET 6 MVC
